# Firebird2.5 error with collation in POSITION

Tags: firebird

Why does the following query succeed in Firebird 2.1, but fail in Firebird 2.5?

```
select POSITION(_UNICODE_FSS 'alcu' IN _UNICODE_FSS 'Calculation') from "Election"
```

The error is

```
Error: *** IBPP::SQLException ***
Context: Statement::Prepare( select POSITION(_UNICODE_FSS 'alcu' IN _UNICODE_FSS 'Calculation') from "Election" )
Message: isc_dsql_prepare failed

SQL Message : -902
can't format message 13:98 -- message file C:\Windows\firebird.msg not found

Engine Code    : 335544721
Engine Message :
Unable to complete network request to host "*******".
Error reading data from the connection.
```

Using other collations like _UTF8 have the same results.

However, queries like

```
select replace (_UNICODE_FSS 'Billy Wilder',  _UNICODE_FSS 'il', _UNICODE_FSS 'oog') from "Election"
```

work in both Firebird 2.1 and 2.5

I'm using the FlameRobin client.

Comment: It sounds like a bug; it looks as if the connection or server crashed. I'd suggest filing a bug on http://tracker.firebirdsql.org